# Javascript nested function not defined

Tags: javascript

Creating a nested function, and then attempting to fill in all function parameters results in an error:

```
function A(x) {
  function B(y) {
    function C(z) {
      console.log(x + y + z);
    }
  }
}

A(2)(2)(2);



>> Uncaught TypeError: A(...) is not a function
```

However on the MDN documentation, a nested function such as the following works correctly:

```
function outside(x) {
  function inside(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
  return inside;
}
fn_inside = outside(3); // Think of it like: give me a function that adds 3 to whatever you give
                        // it
result = fn_inside(5); // returns 8

result1 = outside(3)(5); // returns 8
```

Comment: Compare the example and your code and check for differences. In this case, I see `return` a lot more in the example...

Comment: You defined a function inside of A, A does nothing with the function and returns nothing.

Comment: Indeed `A(2)` is a valid function call, but `A(2)(2)(2)` is not since you dont do returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning your function, what you probably want to do is:

```
function A(x) {
  function B(y) {
    function C(z) {
      console.log(x + y + z);
    }
    return C;
  }
  return B;
}
```

Or, using function expressions:

```
function A(x) {
  return function B(y) {
    return function C(z) {
      console.log(x + y + z);
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

function A does not return anything. This is the equivalent of:

```js
const result = A(2); // result is undefined
result(2); // trying to invoke undefined as a function
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, everything is fine, except that you forgot to return the inner functions.

Instead, you should do it like this:

```js
function A(x) {
  return function B(y) {
    return function C(z) {
      console.log(x + y + z);
    }
  }
}

A(2)(2)(2); //6
```